# probability with two variables - Taking balls out of the basket

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, polya-urn-model

There's 3 balls in the basket - White, red and black. Three people chose one ball after the other with return.
$X$ is the various colors that got chosen.
$Y$ is the number of people that chose white.
I need to calculate $P(X+Y≤3|X-Y≥1)$.

So I got that I need to start from that getting each ball is probability of $1/3$, since it's with return.
I'm getting confused with how Can I compute Y? Can I say it's sort of uniform distribution and maybe to try by that? Meaning, that the expected value is $(a-b)/2$?

Comment: You should not compute $Y$. It is a random number taking on the values $0,1,2,3$. And you can easily compute the probability of each of these 4 values.

Comment: 'various colors that got chosen' - do you mean a list of unique colors, e.g. (W) if everyone selected white?

Comment: @Alex I would assume it is the number of colors chosen at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a probability table of joint outcomes of $(X, Y)$.  Note $X \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $Y \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.  For $X = 1$, there are only the three outcomes $$(w,w,w), (r,r,r), (b,b,b).$$  For $X = 2$, we have $\binom{3}{2}(2^3 - 2) = 18$ outcomes:
$$(r, r, w), (r, r, b), (r, w, r), (r, w, w), (r, b, r), (r, b, b), \\
  (w, r, r), (w, r, w), (w, w, r), (w, w, b), (w, b, w), (w, b, b), \\
  (b, r, r), (b, r, b), (b, w, w), (b, w, b), (b, b, r), (b, b, w).$$
For $X = 3$, we have $3! = 6$ outcomes, which are the permutations of $r, b, w$ in some order.  The total is $3^3 = 27$.

When $X = 1$, we have either $Y = 3$ with probability $1/3$ or $Y = 0$ with probability $2/3$.

When $X = 2$, we have $Y = 0$, $Y = 1$, $Y = 2$ each with probability $1/3$.

When $X = 3$, we have $Y = 1$ with probability $1$.

So we have
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\Pr[X = x, Y = y] & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
1 & \frac{2}{27} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{27} \\
2 & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & 0 \\
3 & 0 & \frac{2}{9} & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$
The rest is simply conditioning.  Select those outcomes for which $X - Y \ge 1$, and among those, tabulate the probabilities for which $X + Y \le 3$.  then divide by the sum of the probabilities that you considered.

Comment: Thanks, That was very helpful. So if I got it right I should get $0.7$ in the end right?

Comment: @JustEquvilant Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There's a total of $3^3$ ways of selecting 3 balls (all balls and all ppl are different).

Given that $X$ is at most $3$ and $Y$ is at most $3$, $X-Y \geq1$ can mean two cases:
$$
1)  X-Y=1 
$$
if either 2 colors/1 white  (WR, WB) or 1 color/0 white (R,B) were chosen.
$$
2) X-Y=2
$$
if either 3 colors/one white (WRB) or 2 colors/0 white (RB). The difference can't be 3, because you can't have all 3 colors selected without selecting white.

For $X+Y$, you have 3 cases:
$$
1)X+Y=1
$$
if (R,B) were chosen
$$
2)X+Y=2
$$
if either one white (W) or (R,B) were chosen and
$$
3)X+Y=3
$$
if either (W,B) or (W,R) were chosen.

Can you put together these cases assuming all sampling was independent and withe replacement?